# c# Subsonic 2.1 : Order by case

Tags: c#, sql, subsonic, sql-order-by

I would like to know if its possible to order by a specific ID in subsonic 2.1.
Same as regular sql query:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE  
WHEN ID = 5 then 1 
WHEN ID = 10 then 2 
WHEN ID = 1 then 3 
WHEN ID = then 4 
else 5 
END
```

I hope someone can help me, I want this functionality for country specific content.

Kind regards,
Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
Dim q As SubSonic.SqlQuery =
    New SubSonic.Select().From(MyTable.Schema)
    .OrderAsc("case when ID = 5 then 1 when ID = 10 then 2 else 5 end")
Dim foo = q.ExecuteAsCollection(Of MyTableCollection)()
```

I don't think there is any SubSonic native, type-safe syntax (i.e. Case().When()...), but this works.